# Pass a function that accepts multiple arguments as an argument to a function

Tags: python

I'm studying how to pass a function as an argument. I've encountered a problem where I tried to invoke a passed-in function which accepts multiple arguments.

Code:

```py
    def add(*numbers):
        total = 0
        for number in numbers:
            total += number
        return total

    def apply(func, value):
        return func(value)


    print(apply(add, (1,2,3)))
```

Output:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "D:\PythonPrac\test.py", line 13, in <module>
        print(apply(add, (1,2,3)))
      File "D:\PythonPrac\test.py", line 9, in apply
        return func(value)
      File "D:\PythonPrac\test.py", line 4, in add
        total += number
    TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'int' and 'tuple'
```

Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have removed asterisk * from numbers in add Function

```
       def add(numbers):
           total = 0
           for number in numbers:
              total += number
           return total

       def apply(func, value):
          return func(value)
```

Answer (score 1):

you are summing up an integer to a tuple :

```
0 + (1,2,3)
```

so when you call it you have to do this:

```
add(1,2,3)
```

or you have to change the add function in this way:

```
def add(numbers):
        total = 0
        for number in numbers:
            total += number
        return total
```

so in this case you iterate trough number  that is a tuple: `(1,2,3)` and not a list of tuple like before: `[(1,2,3)]`

then, it might be a stupid question because you can have your reasons (and maybe it wil be better to you to explain them) but why do you do:

```
apply(add, (1,2,3))
```

instead of:

`add((1,2,3))` or `add(1,2,3)` (it depends if you use your or my version of the add function)

it appear like a nonsense thing that you use a function that ONLY calls another function instead of calling it directly

finally if you want to do it in your way you have to do:

```
def add(*numbers):
        total = 0
        for number in numbers[0]:
            total += number
        return total
```

Comment: Sorry if it was a stupid question, I was following along with this tutorial book where it teaches about decorators. As I was reading, it went to a point where I learned that functions can also be passed as an argument. Then I thought that it would be kinda funny to make a function that calls another function lol. So I tried making one that accepts multiple arguments. Sorry it it was a waste of time but I really appreciate the answer you've given. Also, I'm not good in English and I'm really sorry for that lol. Thank you so much~!

Comment: is not your fault and it was a so bad question, i was just trying to understand what was your objctive to give you the optimal solution

Answer (score 1):

Add an asterisk before values on line 8.

```py
def add(*numbers):
    total = 0
    for number in numbers:
        total += number
    return total

def apply(func, value):
    return func(*value)


print(apply(add, (1,2,3)))
```

**Explenation:**
This unpacks the tuple as arguments, so the evalution will be roughly like this:

```py
apply(add, (1, 2, 3))
add(*(1, 2, 3))
add(1, 2, 3)
```